# QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (110)

When I put this project into another server it works fine . 
Is there any problem with server configuration ?

in database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),



'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'projapati',
        'username' => 'projapati',
        'password' => 'AHt!j![(dl',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

],
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is there any .htaccess or web.config? i had the same issue when I used a particular apache config and it turned out that .htaccess was the problem

Comment: Is the database running?
```
service mysql status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),`

to this

`'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),`